# The issue of refreshing the page when the login status changes

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am developing an app using SwiftUI, and I'm planning to implement a feature where the app checks the login status upon entering and displays either the login page or the main page accordingly. After logging in on the login page, the app should navigate to the main interface. But I met a problem.

I attempted to achieve this using the following approach, but when I change the 'ifLogin' state to true in 'LoginPage()', the page doesn't transition to 'HomeView()'.
Alternatively, are there any better ways to achieve it? I would greatly appreciate it.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginVM : LoginVM()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            if loginVM.loginInfo.isLogin {
                HomeView()
            }else{
                LoginPage()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginPage: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginVM = LoginVM()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Login"){
                loginVM.changeIsLogin()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

class LoginVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var loginInfo = Login(isLogin: false)
    
    func changeIsLogin(){
        loginInfo.changeLoginState()
    }

}
```

```
import Foundation

struct Login {
    var isLogin: Bool
    
    mutating func changeLoginState() {
        isLogin.toggle()
    }
    
    init(isLogin: Bool) {
        self.isLogin = isLogin
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a common mistake: You created two different (independent) instances of `LoginVM`.

Use always **one** instance. Either inject it into the environment or pass it through the view hierarchy.

And since SwiftUI 2 the reference type equivalent of `@State` is `@StateObject` and the equivalent of `@Binding` is `@ObservedObject`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var loginVM = LoginVM()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            if loginVM.loginInfo.isLogin {
                HomeView()
            }else{
                LoginPage(loginVM: loginVM)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginPage: View {
    @ObservedObject var loginVM : LoginVM

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Login"){
                loginVM.changeIsLogin()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The syntax `@ObservedObject var loginVM : LoginVM()` is wrong anyway and doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I understand it now.